# Unicode character didn't reflect in MySql and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, unicode

I have a problem with unicode Chinese character. When I created New Order with remark, I have been typed the Chinese character in Remark textbox. Here screen shoot!
[image]

I'm using MySql (5.5.34) and Datatype is VARCHAR for Remark. Here the screen shoot.

[image]

But, the remark data didn't save properly in Database. Here the screen shoot.

[image]

When I go back to previous order, Remarks Field does not reflect Chinese Character. Please see the screen shoot.

[image]

Please pointing out to me where can I have problem and how to solve this issue. Thanks!

I have on concern about the Mysql CHARSET. This table CHARSET is latin1. So, this might be a problem for unicode!

Answer (score 0):

Latin1 doesn't support Unicode.

MySQL can handle 4 bytes characters since version 5.5.3 by using "utf8mb4" encoding.

The UTF8 encoding only supports the lower plane, the Unicode characters before it was extended.

Comment: UTF-8 supports all of Unicode. Maybe you meant UCS-2 (though I can’t see how this relates).

Comment: I meant the MySQL encoding called UTF-8.